# SetTimeout and Loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

Hello I have a problem in ***Javascript.***

I need that when clicking on a button in HTML, that the *values **0** to **10** appear on the document*, and I want each value to be displayed with a dash before, **but especially 500ms between each among them.**

For this I use the **for loops** and the **SetTimeout function**.

I'll let you read the code.

```js
            let button = document.querySelector("button");
            let p = document.querySelector('p');

            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                for (let i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                            document.write(`- ${i} <br>`);
                        },500) 
                }
            })
```

```html
    <button type="button">Clic</button>
```

But the values are showing up in the same time at once, and not one by one.

Comment: ...and what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setTimeout is an asynchronous function, you've to increase the delay in each iteration

```
    let button = document.querySelector("button");
    let p = document.querySelector('p');

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for (let i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    document.write(`- ${i} <br>`);
                },500 * i) 
        }
    })
```

Comment: thank you it's working